# How do I make my POST request accept my JSON payload in the following format ? I am using Jackson for this operation

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, dropwizard, jackson-databind

How to make this POST request accept payload , where I pass an array of JSON objects. Is there any method to resolve this problem. Any suggestion would help ?

```
package com.fyle.app.resources.lambda;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.Parser;
import com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.Expression;
import com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.impl.NodeUtils;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;



@Path("/api")
public class LambdaFunction {

/**
 * Transform the incoming JSON with JSLT and return the result.
 */
@POST
@Path("/json-post")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String invoke(InputJson json) {
    try {
        // this must be:
        // {"json" : ..., "jslt" : jslt}

        JsonNode input = mapper.convertValue(json.getJson(), JsonNode.class);

        // now we can do the thing
        JsonNode source = NodeUtils.mapper.readTree(input.get("json").asText());
        //String jslt = input.get("jstlTemplateString").asText();
        String jstlTemplateString = json.get("jstlTemplateString");

        Expression template = Parser.compileString(jstlTemplateString);
        JsonNode output = template.apply(source);
        return NodeUtils.mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(output);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        return "ERROR: " + e;
    }
}
```

The JSON Payload it is accepting ::

```
{
 "json":"[{\"Key1\": \"Value1\", \"Key2\": \"Value2\", \"Key3\": \"Value3\"},{\"Key1\":      
 \"Value1\", \"Key2\": \"Value2\", \"Key3\": \"Value3\"},{\"Key1\": \"Value1\", \"Key2\": 
 \"Value2\", \"Key3\": \"Value3\"}]”,

 "jstl":"\n[\nfor (.)\n{\n \"Key-Change-1\" : .Key1,\n \"Key-Change-2\": .\"Key2\",\n \"Key- 
 Change-3\" : .\"Key3\"\n}\n]\n”
}
```

Can we take data only in JSON format without those " \ and \n "

```
{"json": "["key":"value" , "key":"value" , "key":"value"]" , "jslt":"template.jslt"}
```

My payload class ::

```
public class InputJson {
Object json;
String jstlTemplateString;

public Object getJson() {
    return json;
}

public void setJson(Object json) {
    this.json = json;
}

public String getJstlTemplateString() {
    return jstlTemplateString;
}

public void setJstlTemplateString(String jstlTemplateString) {
    this.jstlTemplateString = jstlTemplateString;
}

public String get(String jstlTemplateString) {
    return jstlTemplateString;
}
}
```

This is the class file I'm using but still have the same error. 
I think the problem in with this line

```
JsonNode source = NodeUtils.mapper.readTree(input.get("json").asText());
```

This is expecting the input to be a string instead of JSON objects , Is this the root cause for this problem ?

Comment: `"json":"[{"Key1": "Value1"` looks like invalid jason, better: `"json":[{"Key1": "Value1"}]`

Answer (score 1):

Your "jstl" key is incorrect. Its value is "[for (.){". Then it is expecting ',' before Key-Change-1 begins. Hence the given error. You can use any online json editor to check if your json is correct or not ex. https://jsoneditoronline.org/. If your whole string is value; you have to escape the double quotes part of value using . like {

"jstl":"[for (.){\"Key-Change-1\" : .Key1,\"Key-Change-2\": .\"Key2\",\"Key-Change-3\": .\"Key3\"}]"
}

Edit:

```
class Payload{
    MyJson json;
    Template template;
}

class MyJson{
    String k1;
    String k2;
    .....
}

class Template{
    String t1;
    ......
}
```

Define constructors, getters and setters for these classes and then you can pass Payload object with your POST request.

Comment: you are correct , but I need to pass this data to POST api as JSON objects instead of string.

Comment: Basically what you want is, you have 2 objects in your code String jstl and Expression template, (which you have read successfully), and now want to pass it as POST payload something like: {"json": "json values", "jstl":"jstl values"}

Answer (score 0):

Your method accepts json, not text. You should create a class and pass it. So given the Rahul Agrawal's answer you need to change your code to:

```
@POST
@Path("/json-post")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT/PLAIN)
public String invoke(Payload json) {
    try {


        return NodeUtils.mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(payload);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        return "ERROR: " + e;
    }
}
```

Also note that you return String, not json. So I changed the return type. If you want to return json, just return payload.

Make sure that your jackson providers are registered. I'm almost sure it's already happen in dropwizard, but still worth checking.